# Let $T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Show that $\rho(T) < \rho$ iff there exists a $P\succ0$ such that $ T^{\rm T}PT-\rho^2P \prec 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $\rho(T)$ denote the spectral radius of $T$ and $\rho \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$. Show that
\begin{align}
\rho(T) < \rho
\end{align}
if and only if there exists a $P\succ0$ such that
\begin{align}
 T^{\rm T}PT-\rho^2P \prec 0.
\end{align}

**Sufficiency:**

Let $\lambda \in \text{sp}(T)$ and $x$ be an associated eigenvector. We have:

$$x^T T^T P T x - \rho^2 x^T P x < 0 \implies (Tx)^T P (Tx) < \rho^2 x^T P x$$

and

$$(Tx)^T P (Tx) = (\lambda x)^T P (\lambda x ) = \lambda ^2 x^T P x$$

As $x^T P x>0$, we get $\lambda ^2 < \rho^2$, i.e. $|\lambda| < \rho$. We conclude that $\rho(T) < \rho$ and proves the sufficiency.

**Necessity:**

Suppose that $\rho(T) < \rho$. Suppose towards a contradiction that for each $P\succ0$ it holds that
\begin{align}
 T^{\rm T}PT-\rho^2P \succeq 0.
\end{align}
Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\{0\}$ be an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $|\lambda| = \rho(T)$. Then it holds that
\begin{align}
 x^{\rm T}T^{\rm T}Tx-\rho^2 x^{\rm T} x \geq 0,
\end{align}
since $P=I\succ0$. This implies that
\begin{align}
 |\lambda| \geq \rho > \rho(T),
\end{align}
i.e. a contradiction. This proves the necessity.

Comment: The answers in the duplicate question do not address necessity. The question assumes necessity by supposing $\|Tx\|\le\rho\|x\|$ which is false.

Comment: The alleged duplicate question is entirely different from this one. The current one defines $\rho(T)$ as the spectral **norm** ($=\|T\|_2=$ the largest singular value) of $T$, while the alleged duplicate question defines $\rho(T)$ as the spectral **radius** (= the largest magnitude of all eigenvalues) of $T$. The sufficiency part in your question is actually false. E.g.
$$
\pmatrix{3/4&3/4\\ 0&3/4}\pmatrix{1\\ &\epsilon}\pmatrix{3/4&0\\ 3/4&3/4}\prec\pmatrix{1\\ &\epsilon}
$$
when $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small, but the spectral norm of $\pmatrix{3/4&0\\ 3/4&3/4}$ is greater than $1$.

Comment: @user1551 $\rho(T)$ should denote the spectral radius here too. Sorry about that.